# loop through subfolders in cmd

Tags: cmd

I am using the following in a CMD window to rename all the files in the directory to .pdf
ren *. *.pdf

How can I apply this at a higher level directory to batch through all sub-directories

tried google and found /r but can't make it run without errors.

Comment: Enumerate each directory in the tree,:then rename in each: ```for /f "delims=" %g in ('dir /a:d /b /s 2^>nul') do @ren "%g\*.*" "*.pdf"```

Comment: perfect wish I asked earlier

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop from the command line will work

This will rename all files to *.pdf. Example: filename.txt => filename.txt.pdf

```
for /r %f in (*.*) do ren %f %~f.pdf
```

This will rename all files to .pdf. Example: filename.txt => filename.pdf

```
for /r %f in (*.*) do ren %f %~pnf.pdf
```